# Problem understanding the nested dictionary related problem: Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

If one receiver has the most in each category you have to return his name. If there is no receiver with the max values in all categories you should return 'None of them' also the player with max values should not have any of the values as common.

so for eg receivers should output 'None of them' and receivers2 will output ahmed

```
receivers = ({'abdul': {'a': 1800, 'b': 16, 'c': 110},
              'ahmed' :  {'a': 1900, 'b': 19, 'c': 114},
              'rehman' : {'a': 1600,'b': 19, 'c': 113}})
receivers2 = ({'abdul': {'a': 1759, 'b': 10, 'c': 90}, 
               'ahmed' : {'a': 1955, 'b': 18, 'c': 106}, 
               'rehman' : {'a': 1719,'b': 16, 'c': 102}})


def triple_crown(r):
    for i in r:
        if all(r[i][k]>r[j][k] for k in r[i] for j in r if i!=j):
        return i
    return 'None of them'
```

I have problems understanding this code I understand all() will return true only when all the items inside it are true.
I dont understand the part where he chose j variable if someone could help me understand thank you.

Comment: This is a great example of why variables like: `r`, `i`, `k`, and `j` are terrible.

Answer (score 0):

What if we take that code and expand the names. I think you might be able to understand it better:

```py
def triple_crown(receivers):
    for name_a in receivers:
        if all(
            receivers[name_a][subkey] > receivers[name_b][subkey]
            for subkey in receivers[name_a]
            for name_b in receivers
            if name_a != name_b
        ):
            return name_a

    return 'None of them'
```

Or if we add in a little documentation as we go, I think might help.

```py
def triple_crown(receivers):
    ## ------------------
    ## iterate over all the receivers.
    ## This current receiver (key of name_a) will be used as the driver to
    ## to compare against all receiver (key of name_b)
    ## ------------------
    for name_a in receivers:

        if all(
            ## ------------------
            ## Given 2 "receivers" receivers[name_a] and receivers[name_b]
            ## and a key of their sub-dictionaries "key"..
            ## Is the corresponding value of the first greater than the second.
            ## ------------------
            receivers[name_a][subkey] > receivers[name_b][subkey]
            ## ------------------

            ## ------------------
            ## iterate over all the keys in the sub-dictionary of receivers[name_a]
            ## note that this solution implicitly requires matching keys to exist
            ## for every receiver
            ## ------------------
            for subkey in receivers[name_a]
            ## ------------------

            ## ------------------
            ## iterate over all the receivers again to compare them to
            ## our current receiver (receivers[name_a])
            ## ------------------
            for name_b in receivers
            ## ------------------

            ## ------------------
            ## Ignore this iteration if the two recievers are the same reciever as
            ## their keys are the same
            ## ------------------
            if name_a != name_b
            ## ------------------
        ):
            return name_a

    return 'None of them'
```